# Joining two tables in mysql where one value corresponds to two values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Phone calls:

| Caller | Receiver |
| --- | --- |
| 012345 | 543210 |
| 123123 | 321321 |

People:

| Person | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | 012345 |
| Jane | 123123 |
| Bob | 321321 |
| Gill | 543210 |

How can I join those tables to to get an output like this:

| Caller | Receiver |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | Gill |
| Jane | Bob |

I've tried

```
select * from phone_calls join person on phone_calls.caller = person.number and phone_calls.receiver = person.number
```

but this does not work.

Any help would be apprieciated.

Thank you,
T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the person table twice

> ```
> SELECT p1.`Person`,p2.`Person` FROM phonecalls pc 
> INNER JOIN  Person p1 ON p1.`Number` = pc.`Caller` 
> INNER JOIN  Person p2 ON  p2.`Number` = pc.`Receiver`
> ```
>
> ```
> Person | Person
> :----- | :-----
> Jane   | Bob   
> Jack   | Gill
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=815c79f15dc68f00beb74a7c80147fc1)*

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much, nbk!